# Как использовать дополнительную таблицу в mptt-django

Tags: python, база-данных

**Имеется модели связанные полем многое ко многому:**

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name="Категория")
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
                  **и**
class Produkt(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name="Название")
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='cat', null=True, blank=True)
```

В базе данных создаются таблицы:

1. category
2. produkt
3. produkt_category

Вопрос: как получить поля для views.py из промежуточной таблицы produkt_category если у неё нет модели(класса)?

Comment: Для чего вам получать что-то из этой таблицы? Это техническая таблица django для реализации m2m. Она состоит из 3х полей - собственного id, id category и id produkt.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам необходимо получить все товары в категории, включая те, что относятся к дочерним категориям данной категории, то делается это так:

```
# category - какая либо категория

# получим queryset, в который будет входить сама категория и все вложенные в нее
branch_categories = category.get_descendants(include_self=True)

# Выберем все продукты, которые входят в выбранную категорию, либо в любую вложенную в нее.
category_products = Produkt.objects.filter(category__in=branch_categories).distinct()
```

Comment: Спасибо за код получения дочерних категорий и объектов отнесенных к ним. Помогло решить такую задачу :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7pd4KDnGtk     Но основная задача-  методы позволяющие взаимодействовать с классами связанными  m2m в библиотеке mptt пока мной не решена...

Comment: Я не могу понять, что вы подразумеваете под "взаимодействовать с классами связанными m2m в библиотеке mptt", не могли бы вы пояснить подробнее?

Comment: Интересуют кодовые строки, для функции в view.py,1- которая позволит получить по конкретной категории все товары, и обратное 2 - по товару получить все категории к которому он отнесен.

Answer (score 0):

Прочитав в очередной раз документацию к mptt, решила прислушаться к авторам и не использовать библиотеку в создании связи **многое ко многому**. Мы же не используем микроскоп для наблюдений за звездами, а в телескоп не пытаемся рассмотреть микромир... Библиотека mptt создана для построений "вложенных множеств" или деревовидных структур и её конёк - это отношение **один ко многому**. Проблема получения объектов связанных отношением m2m решилась стандартным django m2m.

> 1.как получить по категории продукт(ы):

categor = Category.objects.get(id=id) - выбираем конкретную категорию

producs = Produkt.objects.filter(category__name__exact= categor)- все продукты из категории
 **обратите внимание на двойное подчеркивание!**

> 2. как получить от продукта его категории:

produc=Produkt.objects.get(id=id) - получить конкретный продукт

получив продукт как объект класса мы имеем все поля относящиеся к нему.Теперь для получения всех категорий в шаблонах или в функциях достаточно указать :

produc.category  - категории относящиеся к конкретному продукту.

> Если не совсем понятно - поясняющее
>   видео:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4lutesqMUQ
>   Или страницы официального туториала:http://djbook.ru/rel1.4/topics/db/queries.html